# Using CiviRules to send email when setting up a Direct Debit

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, recurring-contributions, civirules

We noticed there was a delay of about 6 days when a new member signs up using GoCardless before their membership is current and they receive the usual 'Thank you' email so we've only set up a Rule to send an email to let them know that there will be a delay while the Direct Debit is set up

So currently, it's based on:

- When membership is added
- And membership status is pending
- Contact has recurring payments

However, we have existing members who are just now taking advantage of the Direct Debits function and their membership is not 'added' and their status is still 'current' if they're renewing before the end date.

Is there a way that I can trigger an email for these people?

The only thing possibly to include would be the contribution status (Pending incomplete transaction) but this is still likely to pick up incorrect people since it's used for a variety of scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

If your existing members are getting a new recurring contribution you could potentially check for a new recurring contribution instead of a new membership? I think that would solve the issue.

[image]

If you try and it does not you might try something like:

- a first rule to check for relevant new memberships and add them to a group
- a second rule that adds them to a group when the contact gets a new recurring contribution AND is not already member of the group
- send the email when a contact is added to the group (and potentially remove them from the group if you think that would make sense).

Comment: That was a quick reply! I didn't see the 'recurring payment is added' so that's very useful, thank you. I just need to check with the client now whether the wording needs to be different for renewing and new members with a new recurring payment so whether we need one process or two.